Elasticsearch filter. Laravel. Product-Property-Attribute
I have a Product model. He has a relationship with Property.
public function properties(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Property::class, 'model', 'propertyables');
}

And Property has a relationship with Attribute.
public function attribute()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class);
}

I need to build an index for Elasticsearch so that it filters if the Property is from one Attribute then by the OR operator, and if the Property is from different Attributes then by the AND operator. The usual filter is as in the photo.

